# Coredump during login (before password)

Tags: arch-linux, login, core-dump

After rebooting my laptop, I am asked for a login `archlinux login:`, and I can fill a username, but then the screen simply redraws, instead of asking for a password.

Booting from a live USB and using `arch-chroot`, I could check `journalctl`, and I found that `login` had written coredumps. So I ran `coredumpctl info 612` (truncating the output because I'm transcribing):

```
PID: 612 (login)
UID: 0 (root)
GID: 0 (root)
Signal: 11 (SEGV)
...
Command Line: /bin/login -p --
Executable: /usr/bin/login
...
Unit: getty@tty2.service
...
```

I thought at first that my boot problems were graphics related, because lightDM would crash on me (and there were others who had similar issues which were solved by updating optimus-manager), but here I've `systemctl disable`d lightDM and the crash happens before the password, so there would be no graphical environment involved yet. And this issue is more severe than simple graphics card issues, because switching TTYs doesn't help and I can't access my user to do `pacman` calls.

Do you know anything?